# ARRAYFORMULA - Not Working on CONCATENATE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have the following formula in a Google Sheets document:

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(LOOKUP($D3, MetaData_Classes!$B$3:$B, MetaData_Classes!$D$3:$D), " ", $E3, " ", LOOKUP($D3, MetaData_Classes!$B$3:$B, MetaData_Classes!$E$3:$E)))
```

([Spreadsheet available here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GzpVLIp-PW2Y8_SW42ImBtbxtNnFRWJ7sfZIInBGx1E/edit?usp=sharing), the code is in the 'MetaData_Subclasses' tab in the 'Formatted Subclasses' table).

While quite long, it is basically broken down into the following plain language command:

**Get two values associated with D3, and concatenate them on either side of E3 (trimming whitespace).**

This formula works fine and can be dragged down the entire column it sits in to get the desired results.

However, I wanted to automate this process so that you didn't need to manually copy the formula down the column whenever you add new elements, and it appears `ARRAYFORMULA` was built for this task.

The problem seems to be that `ARRAYFORMULA` doesn't interact well with trying to convert this into a formula it can comprehend. Even just trying the following test command fails:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(D3:D))
```

Because `CONCATENATE` gets to the array values before `ARRAYFORMULA` does (and hence outputs a string containing every element in D3:D back-to-back).

**How can I use a function like `CONCATENATE`, `LOOKUP`, etc while still being able to use `ARRAYFORMULA`?**

Or is there another way to get this formula down the whole column?

Comment: @player0 Link added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, MetaData_Classes!A2:D, 3, 0))&" "&D2:D&" "&
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, MetaData_Classes!A2:D, 4, 0))))
```

[image: 0]